# Kernel of a Linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Sorry if this is a repeted question. I did not find it. The question is

Suppose $T:U \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation between two vector spaces over the same field, such that $dim\, V < dim\, U < \infty$. Show that $\exists u \in U, u\neq 0$ such that $T(u) = 0$.

Thanks!

Comment: In the book this question appears before the kernel-image theorem. Can we show this without it?

Comment: You could show that since $\dim U>\dim V$, the images of elements of a basis for $U$ must be linearly dependent, and therefore deduce that the kernel is nonempty.

Answer (score 0):

This is an immediate consequence of rank-nullity:
$$\dim U=\dim\operatorname{im}T+\dim\ker T\leq\dim V+\dim\ker T\implies\dim\ker T>0.$$
So $\ker T$ has a non-zero element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the kernel-image theorem that says that if you have a linear transformation $T:U\rightarrow V$ between two vector spaces, then: $\textrm{dim}(U)= \textrm{dim ker}(T)+\textrm{dim Im}(T) $. Now, you know that $\textrm{dim Im}(T) \leq \textrm{dim}(V) \leq \textrm{dim}(U)$. Use that to get that $\textrm{dim ker}(T)>0$